# Show Image Element only if image exists in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image

I have two sibling elements. One is image and other is a div. I want to show image element if image exists and show div element if image doesn't exist. My elements looks like

```
 <img ng-show="product.img" ng-src="{{product.img}}" />
 <div class="left margin-right-1 line-height-15" ng-hide="product.img">{{product.img}}</div>
```

And `product.img` results in something like `/assets/images/prod.jpg`. As this is a string so `ng-show` will always be true and image tag will be shown. So if image doesn't exist it will show as broken image. So basically what I want is if image doesn't exist, image tag hides and div is shown and vice versa.

I have tried a javascript function like

```
 $scope.imageExists = function(src) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = src;
  if (image.width == 0) {
      return false;
  } else {
      return true;
  }
}
```

And changed my image tag like

```
 <img ng-show="product.img" ng-src="{{imageExists(product.img)}}" />
```

But this is very expensive. I have 100 products per page and when it loops through all images, the page becomes very very slow.

So can any body guide me what is the best way in angular to show and hide image element if image exists or not.

Comment: You could try ng-if rather than ng-show.  ng-if removes it from the dom.  I can't say, however, what performance enhancements this will make though.

Comment: Why can't `product.img === null` or `undefined` when there's no image?

Comment: `ng-if` doesn't check if image exists or not. I want to check if image exists or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `onError` event in the image to disable the variable that is used in `ng-show`

```
<img ng-show="product.img" ng-src="{{product.img}}" onError="angular.element(this).scope().product.img = false"/>
```

Comment: It says `product not defined`

Comment: Yes, You need to call refer to the scope variable. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using a custom directive.  See Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yBb0rNiXIaO4EGTqCAmm?p=preview

You'll need to attach an `is404` to each of your image:

```
for(var i = 0; i < products.length; ++i) {
    products[i].image.is404 = false;
}
```

Then display them.  You'll need to pass `$index` as an index attribute so you can use it in your directive.

```
<img ng-if="!image.is404" on-src-error index="{{$index}}" src="{{image.image}}" />
<div ng-if="image.is404">Uh oh!  Image 404'd.</div>
```

**Custom directive:**

```
app.directive("onSrcError", function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     element.bind('error', function() {
       //set 404 to true and apply the scope
       scope.images[attrs.index].is404 = true;
       scope.$apply();
     });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I don't want to show any other blank image. I want to hide it and show other element

Answer (score 0):

Those solutions above are good. But I suggest you put `onError` event logic in a directive and use `ng-if` to control the visibility.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('img', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('error', function() {
        scope.ngModel.shown = false;
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  }
})

.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.images = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i == 5) {
      $scope.images[i] = {
        url: 'http://www.notfound.com.fr/404.png'
      };
      continue;
    }
    $scope.images.push({
      url: 'https://unsplash.it/50/50/?random=' + i
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="image in images" ng-init="image.shown=true">
      <p ng-if="!image.shown">
        Empty image here...
      </p>
      <img ng-model="image" ng-if="image.shown" ng-src="{{ image.url }}">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```